# Set footer to a minimum height but more if pushed down?

Tags: css, footer

I am working on a website and I am using WordPress and a custom theme based made with Lubith. It generates the entire theme including CSS however, it doesn't have any option to keep the footer at a minimum distance down and I need to code that in myself. However, I don't know how to do that. So, how can I set the footer to be a minimum amount of pixels down the page and then have it scale with the content once it reaches it.

This is what I believe is the CSS for the footer:

```
#footer {
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    padding: 1px 60px 0 0;
    background: url(images/main-footer.gif) no-repeat center top;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to set a minimum height you can do `min-height:40px;`

Comment: Thanks this fixed the problem with the image disappearing(that was the real problem but the footer insured it wouldn't), but it didn't actually effect the footer. Probably something to do with the way lubith was made. It works though, know it's just time to dial it in.

Comment: glad it helped, ask again if you need